# Array is empty still renders correct data when rendered for first time but after refresh is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The code is

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
var successMsg = req.flash('success')[0];
Section.findOne({'sectionId': 'K111'}, function(err, doc){
    var result = [];
    studentsList = doc.studentsList;

    studentsList.forEach(function(ele){
        Student.findById(ele, function(errs, docs){
            result.push(docs);
        });
    });

    console.log(result);

    res.render('shop/index', {students: result, successMsg: successMsg, noMessages: !successMsg});
});
```

});

Here I am using mongoose for data retrieval from MongoDb.
The result array is empty even after pushing the docs after findById(). The data is correctly rendered for first time when nodejs server starts but after refresh there is not data rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must learn promises or you can use recursion:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var successMsg = req.flash('success')[0];
    Section.findOne({'sectionId': 'K111'}, function(err, doc){
        var result = [];
        studentsList = doc.studentsList;

        function onDone () {
            console.log(result);

            res.render('shop/index', {
                students: result,
                successMsg: successMsg, 
                noMessages: !successMsg
            });
        }

        function findNext(i) {
            if (i == studentsList.length)
                return onDone();

            var ele =  studentsList[i];
            Student.findById(ele, function(err, docs) {
                if (err)
                    return next(err); // Break and go to error handler

                result.push(docs);
                findNext(i + 1);
            });
        }

        findNext(0);
    });
}
```